Just deleted data partition -- please help
I was formatting a USB stick using the Disks tool, and I just deleted a major data partition on an internal HDD. This disk had no OS installed on it; it was purely for storage. I have not attempted to mount or write anything to the disk. I did not erase the data -- I just deleted the partition. facepalm
Can someone please help me recover the data/partition I just deleted?

Does this answer your question? Recover ext4 file system after quick format

Just reset the partition start, end, and type to what they were. The data should not have been touched if all you did was change the partition table.

Thanks for the responses. I'm not sure which filesystem the partition used. My PC has a Windows boot disk (M.2), a Ubuntu boot disk (M.2, which I added later), and this data-only disk, which I use to share data between them. It's an 8TB drive and the system was originally Windows, so likely NTFS? The Disks app says it's a GUID Partition Table and there's a 17MB Microsoft Reserved partition before the free space where my data is.

That Microsoft reserved partition often confuses Testdisk and other recovery tools. It is unformatted space, so without format most tools will not see it, and then tell you to create NTFS partition in wrong place. If NTFS, I would try Windows tools, but do not know if they correctly see a Microsoft reserved. If never installing Windows on a drive, best not to have that partition, Windows requires the reserved partition before first NTFS for any install, but not data only partitions. You had only one partition on a 8TB drive? How did you back that up?

Try using Testdisk application to restore the lost data, data doesnot get erased or deleted actually. But first learn about partitioning numbering to not repeat same mistake twice.

Thank you, this tool did the trick. I just had to specify it was a GPT partition table and analyse the disk, and it correctly detected the deleted partition. I should have done a safety BACKUP of the partition table before writing the changes, but everything seems okay now. Phew.
